# Multiple test sets in Maven

Tags: unit-testing, maven-2

I have written a REST server (in Java using [RestEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy)) with a unit test suite written in Scala. The test suite uses the mock server provided by RestEasy and runs with every Maven build.

I would like to create a second functional test suite that calls an actual tomcat server and exercises each REST service. I do not want this new suite to run with every build, but only on demand, perhaps controlled with a command line argument to Maven.

Is it possible to create multiple independent test suites in a Maven project and disable some from automatic running, or do I need to create a separate Maven project for this functional suite? How can I segregate the different functional suite code if these tests are in the same project with the unit tests (different directories)? How do I run a selected suite with command line arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never used it myself but I am aware of maven integration tests run by the [Maven Failsafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/).

As the [surefire](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) plugin by default includes the tests named `**/Test*.java, **/*Test.java, **/*TestCase.java` the failsafe plugin runs the `**/IT*.java, **/*IT.java, **/*ITCase.java` tests.

Both test approaches have different intentions which seems to match part of your needs. It might be worth to have a look.....

---

Another approach would be to use [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and specifiy different surefire  [includes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) for each profile.